# SQL reservation hotel room query

Tags: php, sql

I  want to create a reservation hotel's room using PHP.

My tables are: `rooms` and `reservations`:

```
rooms
room_id | seats
```

And I have 4 records in this table. 2x 2 seats room and 2x 4 seats room.

```
reservation
reservation_id | room_id | from_time | to_time
```

I want to choose free rooms at any given time.

My query did not take into account every second room.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `rooms`
LEFT JOIN `reservation` ON `rooms.room_id` =`reservation.room_id`
WHERE
    `seats` = 2 
    AND '01/01/2016'BETWEEN `reservation.from_time` AND `reservation.to_time` 
   or '11/02/2016' BETWEEN `reservation.from_time` AND `reservation.to_time`
```

Comment: There is a list of reserved words in mysql ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html ) and your column names (`from` and `to`) are on that list. Use backticks around these fields in the query at the very least!

Comment: What do you want to get using `BETWEEN` and `or`? I believe you want not that thing that it does now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backticks around the fields that have reserved names and also use braces around the conditions in the where clause

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `rooms` r
    left outer join `reservation` rv on r.`room_id`=rv.`room_id`
    where `seats`=2 
      AND (
        '01/01/2016'BETWEEN rv.`from` AND rv.`to` 
        or 
        '11/02/2016' BETWEEN rv.`from` AND rv.`to`
        )
```